# Changing dirs into subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have an Apache 2 on Debian server and I am trying to do dynamic subdomains based on dirnames.
bind is configured corretly for wildcard dns entry.

For example:

There is this specific dir for www for user. Let it be */home/user/sites/nameofthesite/*. Logs for that site are situated in */home/user/sites/logs/nameofthesite/*.

Assuming that users will have more sites than homepage, it’s inconvenient to create for each user a seperate virtual host entry in the configuration file. That’s why I want to rewrite the *nameofthesite* to *nameofthesite.user.example.com*.

I tried several of ways and I still cant do it.
please help ;]

Answer (score 1):

There are may ways to do it. Have you tried the methods described in this document [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html)